# Fit the most chess pieces on a board with these rules

Tags: optimization, chess

Fit the most pieces on a chess board.

- You are only allowed to place Rooks, Knights and Bishops.
- The number of rooks, knights and bishops must be approximately equal (specifically, the number of rooks, knights and bishops must all be either $k$ or $(k+1)$ for some $k$).
- Every piece has to be attacked by exactly one other piece.

I don't know what the answer to this problem is.
Highest legit answer wins, internet bonus points if you can prove that you found the optimum.

Comment: You mean the number of each piece may not be more than **sum** of the numbers of pieces of other two ?(rule #2)

Comment: Sorry, english is not my first language. I mean if you have 3 copies of two pieces, you can have 2, 3, or 4 of the other piece. Maybe you can help me phrase that a bit better. The difference between number of rooks and number of bishops may only be 0 or 1. Same for the other two combination of pieces.

Comment: Maybe: The number of each piece must be within 1 of the number of pieces of each of the other two.

Comment: So if I get this correctly... If I have 2 knights and 3 bishops, I can have 6 rooks?

Comment: @Lolgast No. If you have 2 knights and 3 bishops, you can have 2 or 3 rooks. because for one or less rooks the difference to the bishops would be too big (difference is 2, only 1 or 0 is allowed). and for 4 or more rooks, the difference to the knight number is too big.

Comment: Perhaps author of this puzzle can provide one example each for a valid set of pieces and invalid set.

Comment: The usual assumption in this kind of problems is that all the pieces are the same colour, but can still attack each other. Does this hold here?

Comment: @Bass Let's hope it does... Otherwise it's just a race whoever puts a solution with 21 white rooks, 21 white bishops and 22 white knights.

Comment: @Tweakimp btw, I'd like to make a bruteforce for this to check optimality. Don't wanna do it to soon though, since others (well, and myself perhaps) should be allowed to try manually first. Just give me a poke when you think we're far enough!

Comment: @Lolgast souinds great! After the inital confusion with the number of pieces, i thought about changing the rules to "number of rooks, bishops and knights have to be the same". maybe you can start with that problem :)

Comment: @Lolgast looks like the accepted answer wasn't optimal, found a better one. Now the new one though.. I can't find an alternate place for *any single piece*, even if I try to move other pieces around to build one. That would seem to imply that for the particular approach of "rooks on one color, in maximal clusters, threatened only by each other", that answer is almost certainly a hard maximum. Would really like to know if it's a global maximum too, so if you have the means to brute-force it, please do!

Comment: Looking at it again, C8 *is* a valid spot for an extra knight (forbidden because there aren't enough rooks), and there are 2 knights that have no blocking or attacking duties (A2 and A4), so either of them could be moved there. So the answer isn't *absolutely* locked in place, but only just about nearly. Fitting an entire rook on that board seems utterly impossible though.

Comment: @Bass do you think the riddle would be "better" if i changed the rule to equal amounts of rooks, knights and bishops? And then challenge you to get to 9? :)

Comment: @tweakimp sure, but only if you did it with conclusive evidence that such a configuration is possible. The problem with open-ended puzzles is that it’s hard to know when to stop. (I think I’m stopping here though, since the other rook strategies I tried were not at all better)

Comment: @Bass ok... at this point im just waiting for Lolgast to do the bruteforcing :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

POST MORTEM EDIT (well, post-tick, anyway)
There was way too much flexibility left in the earlier solution, I just had to keep wiggling everything until I got a bishop on the other long diagonal too. Here it is:

> [image: 9 knights, 9 bishops, 8 rooks]
>  9 knights, 9 bishops and 8 rooks, for a total of 26 pieces.

Please do double check it; I checked it several times already, but wishful thinking often makes it impossible to see one's own mistakes.

POST POST MORTEM EDIT:
Here’s a completely different approach with the same result (now with much more symmetry)

> [image: more symmetrical 998]
>  9 knights, 9 bishops, 8 rooks = 26 pieces.
>
>  This time much easier to confirm: the rooks attack *everything* except the very corners, nothing else attacks anything, except the corner bishops that attack each other.

The original accepted answer is below the line.

---

Remorselessly stealing [Daniel Duque's incredible solution](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/57369/36023), which had just enough wiggle room to add another knight:

> 25 pieces (9 knights, 8 bishops, 8 rooks)
>  [image: 9N 8B 8R]

---

Here's another with the same number of pieces, but with a lot more room for improvement, it seems (I hope there aren't any mistakes, I'm getting pretty cross-eyed here..)

> [image: own 9n 8r 8b]
>  9 knights, 8 bishops, 8 rooks = 25 pieces
>  (There are lots of promising lookin variations going on in here, please feel free to use this one in your own answer)

---

Here's my first (original) attempt with

> 20 pieces: 7 bishops, 7 knights and 6 rooks. (with some wiggle room left in the bottom middle)

Like so:

> [image: 7B,7N,6R, each threatened exactly once]
>  As you can probably tell, squeezed everything together by starting with a greedy approach with the difficult pieces on the top side.

Comment: Just in case anyone (let's say, someone without enough fake internet points to add a comment) wonders, when I stole the answer, I did move a rook from H5 to F3 to create a legal spot for the extra knight at F1.

Comment: I'll accept this answer as the best one. Nice!

Comment: @Tweakimp Does that mean I can start bruteforcing? :D

Comment: Do it! After the inital confusion with the number of pieces, I thought about changing the rule to equal amount of knights, rooks and bishops. maybe you can start with that problem. :)

Answer (score 9):

Here is my second attempt with:

> 8 Bishops, 8 Knights and 8 Rooks for a total 24 pieces.

I did it using the following configuration:

> [image]

Answer (score 3):

> $29$, obtained via integer linear programming:

> \begin{matrix}B&B&N&B&N&B&N&R\\.&.&.&R&.&R&.&.\\.&.&R&.&.&.&.&.\\.&N&.&N&.&N&.&N\\R&.&.&.&R&.&.&.\\.&R&.&.&.&.&.&.\\B&B&N&B&N&B&N&B\\.&.&.&R&.&R&.&B\\\end{matrix}

> $28$, obtained via integer linear programming:

> \begin{matrix}B&.&.&.&R&.&B&.\\.&.&.&N&.&R&B&.\\B&.&.&.&R&.&N&.\\B&N&.&N&.&.&B&R\\N&.&R&.&.&.&N&.\\B&N&.&N&.&.&B&R\\N&.&R&.&.&.&N&.\\.&R&.&R&.&.&B&.\\\end{matrix}

> $27$, obtained via integer linear programming:

> \begin{matrix}R&N&.&.&B&.&.&N\\N&B&.&.&B&.&R&R\\.&.&.&R&B&.&.&N\\B&.&R&.&N&.&.&B\\.&.&.&.&.&R&.&.\\.&R&.&.&.&.&.&.\\N&N&N&.&.&B&.&B\\R&N&.&.&.&B&.&R\\\end{matrix}

Comment: I always get a chuckle when you show up--someone will ask "How did you get your answer?"  And subconsciously I'll be like "Duh, ~sorcery~ ILP."  It's always cool to see the work of someone who is skilled in something I'm not.  It's the same way with @codewarrior0 exhuming all these old cipher posts.

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to fit in

> 6 rooks, <strike>6</strike> 5 knights and 5 bishops (<strike>17</strike> 16 pieces total)

Using this setup:

> [image]

It's based on the following principles:

> The rooks attack each other, and the other outgoing rays are blocked by other pieces.
>  The bishops also attack each other and are positioned such that they don't attack any other pieces.

EDIT: Had to remove one piece since it was inadvertently attacking another piece, as noted by Ibrahim mahrir.

Comment: The bishop at **G4** is attacked by two (the knight at **F6** and the rook at **G5**).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I fixed it now, at the expense of one piece.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution using:

> 6 Bishops, 6 Knights, 5 rooks.

In the following configuration:

> [image]

And here is an improvement to the solution given by Lolgast. I was able to add:

> One Knight in (A,4). 
>  [image]

Comment: `>!` for spoilerless quotes.

Comment: Here is the whole [**guide**](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/editing-help#spoilers).

Answer (score 1):

To start off the discussion, here is a solution with:

> 5 knights, 5 bishops and 4 rooks

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

If i understood the **3rd rule** correctly

> Every piece has to be attacked by exactly one other piece.

the solution must be

> the answer must be 12 = 4bishopes + 4knights +4rooks

**the solution image look like exactaly one piece is to be attacked by other
and there are a number of ways you can rearrange the solution**

> [image]

**if you putting more any three of them(bishope, rooks, knights) then it would not fit into the solution because it attacks more than one piece on the board or increase the number of attacks by other pieces on the board both of them violates the 3rd rule like this image below:-**

> [image]

Comment: Just because _your_ solution doesn't allow any more pieces to be added (Note: You actually could add a knight on a3 and a bishop on h2), that doesn't mean your solution is _the_ solution. I'd suggest taking a look at the other answers - They adhere to the 3rd rule as well. EDIT: The 3rd rule only specifies that every piece can __be attacked__ by only one piece, not that it can only __attack__ one piece.

Comment: @Loglast i have taken a closer look at the solutions submitted by others either they are not attacking or they are attacking more than 1 and the rule number 3 says it has to attack one no more no less

Comment: 3rd rule says that each piece **has to be attacked** once, and only once. It has nothing to do with how many other pieces each piece attacks as long as it is attacked only once. It is a fun game; I'll give it a third try tonight when I get home.